# How to select a list of embedded documents as root elements

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

I am using MongoDB with mongocsharpdriver. An example of my data is below. I would like to find a list of all the "transactions" across all "categories". How can I get a list of all the transactions using the collection.find method? Does the query need to make the "transactions" at root level?

Here is my document:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53791916a33e851d2c7ec8f0"),
    "name" : "Shopping",
    "transactions" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53791916a33e851d2c7ec8ee"),
            "date" : "12/01/2012",
            "description" : "mid week",
            "amount" : 12
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53791916a33e851d2c7ec8ef"),
            "date" : "12/01/2012",
            "description" : "end of week",
            "amount" : 5
        }
    ]
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53791a63a33e851d2c359290"),
    "name" : "Entertainment",
    "transactions" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53791a63a33e851d2c35928e"),
            "date" : "12/01/2012",
            "description" : "games",
            "amount" : 70
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53791a63a33e851d2c35928f"),
            "date" : "12/01/2012",
            "description" : "films",
            "amount" : 20
        }
    ]
}
```

In robomongo I use: db.Categories.find({}, {_id:0, transactions:1})

And Get:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "transactions" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53791916a33e851d2c7ec8ee"),
            "date" : "12/01/2012",
            "description" : "mid week",
            "amount" : 12
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53791916a33e851d2c7ec8ef"),
            "date" : "12/01/2012",
            "description" : "end of week",
            "amount" : 5
        }
    ]
}

/* 1 */
{
    "transactions" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53791a63a33e851d2c35928e"),
            "date" : "12/01/2012",
            "description" : "games",
            "amount" : 70
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53791a63a33e851d2c35928f"),
            "date" : "12/01/2012",
            "description" : "films",
            "amount" : 20
        }
    ]
}
```

That is not exactly what I want, the query should return:

```
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53791916a33e851d2c7ec8ee"),
            "date" : "12/01/2012",
            "description" : "mid week",
            "amount" : 12
        }

        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53791916a33e851d2c7ec8ef"),
            "date" : "12/01/2012",
            "description" : "end of week",
            "amount" : 5
        }

        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53791a63a33e851d2c35928e"),
            "date" : "12/01/2012",
            "description" : "games",
            "amount" : 70
        }

        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("53791a63a33e851d2c35928f"),
            "date" : "12/01/2012",
            "description" : "films",
            "amount" : 20
        }
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why did this get a down vote? I am new to mongodb and this is a genuine question...

Comment: At least leave a comment if you are going to down vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you want to reshape the structure of your output, you will typically want to use `aggregate` instead of `find`.  In this case you can use the `$unwind` and `$group` operators to achieve what you want.

In the shell:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
  // Duplicate each doc, once per transactions element.
  {$unwind: '$transactions'},
  // Regroup transactions back together into one big array.
  {$group: {_id: null, transactions: {$push: '$transactions'}}}
  ])
```

Output:

```js
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "transactions" : [ 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("53791916a33e851d2c7ec8ee"),
                    "date" : "12/01/2012",
                    "description" : "mid week",
                    "amount" : 12
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("53791916a33e851d2c7ec8ef"),
                    "date" : "12/01/2012",
                    "description" : "end of week",
                    "amount" : 5
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("53791a63a33e851d2c35928e"),
                    "date" : "12/01/2012",
                    "description" : "games",
                    "amount" : 70
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("53791a63a33e851d2c35928f"),
                    "date" : "12/01/2012",
                    "description" : "films",
                    "amount" : 20
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Or just `$project` only the transactions field rather than `$group` as it still gives the result and should come at less cost. Super handy when running MongoDB 2.6 and greater as all the results are a cursor, rather than in one document.